# SHA256 an uploaded file in Yesod - Using Conduit and Data.Digest.Pure.SHA

Tags: haskell, yesod, sha, conduit

I am handling a file upload using yesod, and would like to save the uploaded file to a file on my server with the name being the SHA256 of the contents.

I think the handler-level function will look like:

```
fileMove fInfo (basePath <> generateSha fInfo)
```

This question is centered around how to write `generateSha :: FileInfo -> String`.

I see a few functions that are likely to be helpful:

```
fileSource :: MonadResource m => FileInfo -> Source m ByteString
sha256Incremental :: Decoder SHA256State
completeSha256Incremental :: Decoder SHA256State -> Int -> Digest SHA256State
showDigest :: Digest t-> String
```

But I'm unsure of a few things:

1. How to wire this up in the conduit. Ideally I'd have it stream the file.
2. Use the SHA interface to incrementally build up the hash. I can get the SHA256 of an empty string easily enough, but I'm not sure how to  add values.  Presumably it's something hidden in the Decoder type?
3. What the `Int` argument of completeSha256Incremental is.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's a different implementation, but I'd recommend checking out [cryptohash-conduit](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2015-07-18/cryptohash-conduit-0.1.1/Crypto-Hash-Conduit.html), which is built on top of the [cryptohash](https://www.stackage.org/package/cryptohash) package (and written by the same author).

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer.  I am stuck in cabal hell right now and can't install `sha-streams` to see if things work right.

Calculating a SHA256 incrementally is done like this:

```
sha256FromChunks :: [ByteString] -> Digest SHA256State
sha256FromChunks cs = completeSHA256Incremental $
                          foldl pushChunk sha256Incremental cs
```

`pushChunk` is from `Data.Binary.Get`.  That shows you how all the function calls fit together, but isn't very practical for a streaming scenario.

To use this with conduit, you would need to turn it into a `Sink`.

Comment: This doesn't compile due to the missing `Int` argument to `completeSha256Incremental`. Do you know what the `Int` is for?

Comment: I looked at the source, and the parameter's name is `pad`.  It's used for zero-padding the end of the input data.  I would assume that using 0 for it doesn't pad anything, which is probably what you want.